# Do the parts of exploration achievements for each act reset between logins if you haven't completed them?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

On my second time logging in to play (first play-through), on the quest to kill the skeleton king, I decided to also pick up the Act 1 exploration achievements, like `A Nice Place to Visit` and `Thorough Investigation`.

I discovered that I hadn't received credit for any of the sections of `A Nice Place to Visit`, most of which I had clearly already passed through, but was forced to revisit.

Do these sub-sections of exploration achievements get wiped, if you haven't completed the full achievement, when the maps are regenerated on login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they don't reset. What you're experiencing is a bug (that is, as far as I know, still not fixed) where achievements don't get transmitted to the server correctly and thus disappear again after starting a new session.

For example, [here's](http://www.vg247.com/2012/05/17/diablo-iii-error-37-strikes-again-awesome-bonus-level-discovered/) a section from a news article about it:

> Those users lucky enough to make it in have reported quite a number of issues. One which is drawing particular ire is the apparent loss of achievements, although responses in a Blizzard forum thread on the matter suggest the servers may just be playing catch up; the developer noted that the achievements server is getting hammered.

Comment: Ah, so this has nothing to do with the map regeneration then? Just that the achievement servers registered blank when I logged in again. I had no other achievements to benchmark against.

Comment: Yes. Maps always get reset completely when you start a new session (with the exception of potential quest events).